# Can anyone tell me why my program is giving me a output of fizz9 instead of just fizz?

Tags: java, boolean-logic

Can anyone tell me why my program is giving me a output of fizz9 instead of just fizz?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class fizzbuzz here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class FizzBuzz
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        boolean fizz = n % 3 == 0;
        boolean buzz = n % 5 == 0;
```

I can only use fizz and buzz in the conditions.

```
        if (fizz)

        {
           System.out.println("fizz"); 
        }
        if (buzz)
        {
            System.out.println("buzz"); 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(n); 

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: the 1st `if (...) { ... }` is separated from the 2nd `if (...) { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `else` statement. If `n` is a multiple of 3 (but not 5), `fizz` will be true (thus printing "fizz"). However, `buzz` will be false (thus printing `n`).

Are you sure you want to print `n` at all? Maybe you meant to check to make sure that both `fizz` and `buzz` were false? (If so, you should change it from `else` to `else if (!fizz)`).